# Is there any way to concatenate numpy arrays out of memory (on disk)?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, memory

I have a process that executes in Python 2.7 with [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) in batches, and generates numpy `float64` arrays that are roughly the following size:

- dimension A: 12
- dimension B: 2000
- dimension C: 89

Right now they are processed within each batch and condensed with some statistical analysis. This is manageable (12 × 2000 × 89 × 8 bytes/float = approx 17MB) But I would like to do some analysis on my entire dataset.

I need to somehow concatenate the batches along dimension B to at least a size of 1000000, which would imply 8.5GB, and then split them among dimension C to analyze each AxB two-dimensional matrix separately. (12x1000000 is "only" 96MB for each element along dimension C and that is more manageable.) But I don't have that much memory on my system, and likely I will need to go to 2000000 or 4000000.

Is there a way to do the concatenation and slicing on disk, so I don't need to have the entire matrix in memory?

Comment: You could use [`numpy.memmap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html), but the disk access patterns might be pretty inefficient. (The memory access patterns would probably be pretty inefficient too if you did this in memory, though.)

Comment: Don't forget the "buy more RAM" option, which is often pretty reasonable.

Comment: I don't remember if it's possible, but `h5py` provides a pretty numpy-like view of data on the disk.  You might be able to make that work...

Comment: 34GB RAM (+ extra for margin) to support 4000000 but my laptop "only" allows a max of 16GB and that's after going through our corporate I/S department :/ no thanks

Comment: @mgilson huh I wonder if pytables can do this

Answer (score 0):

[Pytables EArray](http://www.pytables.org/usersguide/libref/homogenous_storage.html#earrayclassdescr) looks like it can help; I created a proof of concept:

```
import tables
import numpy as np
fh = tables.open_file('bigarray.h5', mode='w')
atom = tables.Float64Atom()
filters = tables.Filters(complevel=5, complib='zlib')
bigarray = fh.create_earray(fh.root, 'bigarray', atom, shape=(0,89,12), filters=filters)
chunksize = 2000
nchunks = 25
for k in xrange(nchunks):
    if k%10 == 0:
        print k
    x0 = np.arange(89,dtype=np.float64)
    y0 = np.arange(12,dtype=np.float64)
    z0 = np.arange(chunksize,dtype=np.float64)+k*chunksize
    x,z,y=np.meshgrid(x0,z0,y0)
    bigarray.append(x*y*z)
print "shape:", bigarray.shape
print bigarray[10000:10100,1,:]
fh.close()
```

which prints out as

```
0
10
20
shape: (50000, 89, 12)
[[      0.   10000.   20000. ...,   90000.  100000.  110000.]
 [      0.   10001.   20002. ...,   90009.  100010.  110011.]
 [      0.   10002.   20004. ...,   90018.  100020.  110022.]
 ..., 
 [      0.   10097.   20194. ...,   90873.  100970.  111067.]
 [      0.   10098.   20196. ...,   90882.  100980.  111078.]
 [      0.   10099.   20198. ...,   90891.  100990.  111089.]]
```

and takes 62.4MB on disk for 50000*89*12 elements (1.17 bytes per element using compression).